# Get parent object plus its child count without anonymous type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I have the next method (which works) to return a list of `claims` plus its `observations`. One claim can have zero-or-many observations. Code works but I'm afraid its a mess, with the anonymous type and then parsing it into a new Claim type, setting the count.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaims(ClaimStatusCode status, int take = 10, int skip = 0)
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {    
        var pendingclaims = await (from claim in db.Claims
                                where claim.OfficeCode == _officeCode
                                where claim.ClaimStatusCode == status
                                select new
                                {
                                    ID = claim.ID,
                                    ClaimStatusCode = claim.ClaimStatusCode,
                                    OpenDate = claim.OpenDate,
                                    LastUpdateDate = claim.LastUpdateDate,
                                    CloseDate = claim.CloseDate,
                                    ProductCode = claim.ProductCode,
                                    IssueCode = claim.IssueCode,
                                    SpecificIssueCode = claim.SpecificIssueCode,
                                    OfficeCode = claim.OfficeCode,
                                    Summary = claim.Summary,
                                    ObservationsCount = claim.Observations.Count
                                }).OrderBy(c => c.OpenDate).Take(take).Skip(skip).ToListAsync();                     

        var list = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (var claim in pendingclaims)
        {
            Claim c = new Claim()
            {
                ID = claim.ID,
                ClaimStatusCode = claim.ClaimStatusCode,
                OpenDate = claim.OpenDate,
                LastUpdateDate = claim.LastUpdateDate,
                CloseDate = claim.CloseDate,
                ProductCode = claim.ProductCode,
                IssueCode = claim.IssueCode,
                SpecificIssueCode = claim.SpecificIssueCode,
                OfficeCode = claim.OfficeCode,
                Summary = claim.Summary,
                ObservationsCount = claim.ObservationsCount
            };
            list.Add(c);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

I think maybe I'm missing something to reduce the mess of the resulting SQL query, but don't figure what. Any idea?

**UPDATE**

As requested, here's the Claim and Observation class, I'm using a plain simple Entity Code First One to Many relationship:

Claim

```
public class Claim
{
    public Claim()
    {
        Observations = new List<Observation>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Observation> Observations { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int ObservationsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Observation

```
public class Observation
{
    public Observation()
    { }

    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Guid ClaimID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClaimID")]
    public virtual Claim Claim { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sure, the observation table is pretty complex and expensive. I can't load all the Observation data for each Claim with a select and `Include`.

Comment: For the previous commenters: EF does not allow projecting to entity type, so intermediate anonymous projection is used to workaround that limitation.

Comment: @RandolfRincónFadul Can you show the `Claim` class? I'm wondering if you select all the fields for that class? And I guess the `ObservationsCount` is unmapped property?

Comment: @IvanStoev, yeah, EF doesn't allow it. Yes, I'm selecting all the fields. And I'm using Entity Code First for the One to Many relationship 'Virtual ICollection' for the Claim to Observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in EF6 to get what you want without some intermediate projection (being it anonymous type or concrete type, as soon as it's not an entity type). But if you need all the object fields plus child count, you can simplify the implementation like this:

```
var pendingclaims = await (from claim in db.Claims.AsNoTracking()
                           where claim.OfficeCode == _officeCode
                           where claim.ClaimStatusCode == status
                           orderby claim.OpenDate
                           select new
                           {
                               claim,
                               ObservationsCount = claim.Observations.Count
                           }).Take(take).Skip(skip).ToListAsync();                     

return pendingclaims.Select(item =>
{
    item.claim.ObservationsCount = item.ObservationsCount;
    return item.claim;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Query part did work. But as for the second part, the projection doesn't match method signature. So ended up creating the list. +1 and thank you for remembering the important `AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: You are welcome :) And sorry for the silly mistake, fixed.